# Controlar Menu php

Tags: php, mysql

Bueno me explico tengo 2 menus , uno para el usuario y el otro para el administrador lo que quiero es que al teclear por ejemplo ruta/admin no pueda acceder a su index otra opcion es que solo fuera un solo menu para ambos pero dependiendo del usuario logueado pueda ver ciertas cosas

este es el index del admin

```html
<?php 


if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
 if($_SESSION['usuario']['perfil'] != "administrador"){
  header("Location: ../usuario/");
 }
}else {
 header('Location : ../');
}


 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="es">
 <head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial=scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/sty.css">
  <title>Inicio</title>
  
 </head>
 <body>

  <div id="menu">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="usuarios.php">Usuarios</a></li>
    <li><a href="ordenes.php">Ordenes</a></li>
    <li><a href="devolucion.php">Devoluciones</a></li>
    <li><a href="../php/salir.php">Cerrar Sesion</a></li>
  </ul>
   

  </div>
 
 </body>
 </html>
```

y este es el index del usuario

```html
<?php 

   <?php 



if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
if($_SESSION['usuario']['perfil'] != "usuario"){
 header("Location: ../admin/");
}
}else {
header('Location : ../');
}


 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="es">
 <head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial=scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/sty.css">
  <title>Inicio</title>
  
 </head>
 <body>

  <div id="menu">
   <ul>
    
    <li><a href="ordenes.php">Ordenes</a></li>
    <li><a href="devolucion.php">Devoluciones</a></li>
    <li><a href="../php/salir.php">Cerrar Sesion</a></li>
 </ul>
   

  </div>
 
 </body>
 </html>
```

anteriormente estaba con `session_start()` pero había un problema al incluirlos en los demás archivos decía que `session_start()` ya fue usada y sera omitida .

primero tenia un problema que al escribir por ejemplo `ruta/admin/archivo.php` podía ingresar normalmente pude solucionar este error quitando la linea de `session_start()` de los index ya que si lo dejaba en los `index` al estar incluido en los demás archivos me decía que `session_start` sera omitido .

como puedo hacer que cada usuario tenga su index ("que solo es una barra de navegación") o hacer que solo sea un `index` y dependiendo del tipo de usuario pueda ver las categorías y gracias.

aclaro los que tienen el mismo nombre tanto en el menu de admin como el usuario son diferentes

Answer (score 0):

yo soy nuevo tambien en esto pero pude una hacer una cosa en el archivo .php del login.

Puedes hacer lo mismo y es que cuando este en sesion el usuario, haga un display: inline en la parte que quieres que vea y display: none en las parte que no quieres que el usuario vea.

Yo lo haria por medio de las etiquetas div con un class llamado por ejemplo "invisible", y a este asigarle el estilo de display: none, asi nadie lo ve.
Despues, hacer con los if si el usuario es admin, un display: inline unicamente para las partes que quieres que el admin vea.

Para la parte de que el user no pueda acceder al archivo admin, seria posible hacer un if donde si es admin le haga location ../admin y debajo un else que haga location ../ .

No se si lo entenderas, pero es facil en realidad.

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo lo que debes hacer es establecer en tu login con $_SESSION que el usuario existe y dependiendo del campo PERFIL muestre si es admin o no.

Ejemplo

CONEXION A TU BASE DE DATOS

```
<?php 

$dbServername="localhost";
$dbUsername="root";
$dbPassword="";
$dbName="bd";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
 ?>
```

TU ARCHIVO LOGIN

```
<?php 

session_start();


include_once 'CONEXION.php';


if($conn->connect_error){
    die("DataBase Conection ERROR: ". $conn->connect_error);
}


$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$query= "SELECT * FROM tablaquecontienetodoslosusuarios WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";

$resultquery= $conn->query($query);

if($resultquery->num_rows > 0){

    $_SESSION['loggedin']=true;
    $_SESSION['username']=$username;
    $_SESSION['start']=time();
    $_SESSION['expire']= $_SESSION['start']+(5*80);

    echo "<h1>Bienvenido: " . $_SESSION['username']. "</h1>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br><h3><a href='../MIPAGINAPRINCIPAL.php'>Acceder a mi cuenta</a></h3>";



}else{
    echo "Usuario o Password son Incorrectos!";
    echo "<br><a href='../index.php'>Porfavor, Volver a intentarlo</a>";
}

mysqli_close($conn);

 ?>
```

Ahora que menu quieres que se muestre? Pues eso lo defines en MIPAGINAPRINCIPAL.PHP

TU PAGINA PRINCIPAL

```
<?php 
session_start();

include_once 'header.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin']==true && ($_SESSION['username']=='Administrador' || $_SESSION['username']=='administrador')){

    echo 
"El cuerpo del menu que quieres mostrar... O tamnbien puedes
";

requiere_once 'MENUADMINISTRADOR.php';



}else if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true){

            echo "Cuerpo del menu sino es admin... O tambien";
           requiere_once 'MENUUSUARIONORMAL.php';

}


include_once 'footer.php';
 ?>
```

INFORMACION EXTRA:

Puedes fijarte que en donde se evalua si es administrador se poner directamente que el username sea administrador.

Pero puedes simplemente hacer una busqueda en tu TABLAQUECONTIENETODOSTUSUSUARIOS
y que verifique que Usuario: ANA o usuario: PEPITO tengan en su campo PERFIL: Administrador.

ejemplo:

```
$tipo=$_SESSION['tipo'];

    $query="SELECT perfil FROM TABLAQUECONTIENETODOSTUSUSUARIOS WHERE username='".$_SESSION['loggedin']."' LIMIT 1";
    $resultquery=mysql_query($conn,$query1);

if(mysqli_num_rows($resultquery)>0){

while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultquery)){

    $tipo=$fila['perfil'];
}


}
```

y afuera del ciclo dices:

```
$_SESSION['tipo']=$tipo;
```

En en donde vas a evaluar que es admin pones que si tu variable $_SESSSION tiene un perfil administrador y listo amigo

SUERTE!

Answer (score -1):

Algo así funciona en Codeigniter (MCV PHP):

Dependiendo del perfil se pintarán unas u otras opciones de menú.

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
<?php if($_SESSION['usuario']['perfil'] == "administrador") { ?>

        <li><a href="ordenes.php">Ordenes</a></li>
        <li><a href="devolucion.php">Devoluciones</a></li>
        <li><a href="../php/salir.php">Cerrar Sesion</a></li>

<?php }else{ ?>

        <li><a href="ordenes.php">Ordenes</a></li>
        <li><a href="../php/salir.php">Cerrar Sesion</a></li>

<?php } ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Amigo, esta respuesta es considerada de baja calidad. Por favor editala, agregá más codigo especifico y explica el funcionamiento del mismo, de lo contrario probablemente sea eliminada.

Comment: Hola amigo, ahora se entiende mejor, creo.

Comment: no @hsp debes darle editar y agregar también una explicación

Comment: Vale, ahora sí está más claro.